# Plot::plld: Endpoints for x in {x,-10,-10} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am pretty new to Mathematica. Have a look at this please:

```
Clear[sol1];
ParallelEvaluate@Clear[sol1];
sol1 = DSolve[f''''[x] - f''[x] + f[x] == x, f, x]
Show[{Plot[
   y[x] /. sol1 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1, C[3] -> 1, 
     C[4] -> 1}, {x, -10, -10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic}]
```

I am getting following error:

> Plot::plld: Endpoints for x in {x,-10,-10} must have distinct
>   machine-precision numerical values. Show::gcomb: Could not combine the
>   graphics objects in Show[{Plot[y[x]/. sol1/.
>   {C[1]->1,C[2]->1,C[3]->1,C[4]->1},{x,-10,-10},PlotStyle->{Red}]},PlotRange->{{-10,10},Automatic}].

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, I have changed f and y. Yes , you are right, it should be -10, 10. Also how can I adjust C coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {x,-10,-10}

You want to plot from $-10$ to $-10$ ? I guess you want $[-10,10]$.

Another thing is your solutions substitution. You want to substitute to `y[x]`, but you defined a `f`. You also get back a Function. Therefore you can call it that way.

```
sol1=DSolve[f''''[x]-f''[x]+f[x]==x,f,x];
func=(f/.sol1/.{C[1]->1,C[2]->1,C[3]->1,C[4]->1})[[1]];
Show[{Plot[func[x],{x,-10,10},PlotStyle->{Red}]},PlotRange->{{-10,10},Automatic}]
```

[image]

(Your `ParallelEvaluate@Clear[sol1];` makes no sense btw.)

Comment: Thanks @Julien. How can I employ boundary conditions? My aim is to find f whenl x is between 0 and 1. Also How about if my right hand side is an array of numerical values.

Comment: @meva, dont pile new questions on an old one. You should accept this answer and ask a new specific question.

Comment: @george2079 I do not know how to accept it ? Can you inform me pls, thanks if so.

Comment: there should be a big check mark under the voting buttons at upper left of the question (I'm not sure if it would be still available since the question was closed )